# Defining a basis for Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the standard basis for polynomials of degree *n* is

{${1,x,x^2,...,x^n}$}

but why is the 1 in there? After all, can't 1 be written as a linear combination, where

$c_1 = 1/x$

and

$1 = x*c_1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c_1=1/x$ is neither a scalar nor a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the notion of a basis, see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29